# How google file system handles files writing (and reading)?

Tags: linux, operating-system, filesystems

I hope question is not too specific, or discussion like. If so please close and comment where I can ask it.

So I started reading gfs paper, but since my background is not very os oriented, I am curious how it handle files.

**Question is:**
Does part of software which receives data (file), uses normal way of handling files (like http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/cfileio.html), or uses different ways? How it works?

Answer (score 0):

The similar concept to the file handle in traditional file system in Google File System is the chunk handle. Each file in Google File System consists of many chunk and each chunk is identified by a 64 bits chunk handle.

The file handle in traditional file system is unique in the memory space in a machine. On the other hand, Google File System is an additional layer over Linux file system, the chunk handle in Google File System is globally unique among all chunk servers.

When performing reading operation, the application send a request to GFS master server to get the chunk metadata, then send chunk metadata to the master server again to get the chunk handle and location. Now the application knows where the chunk is located then send chunk metadata to the chunk server to get chunk content.

When performing writing operation, the application needs to ask master server where to place the chunk, then send chunk content to the designated chunk server. The rest of operations are similar.